# Removing Collectives™ from Stack Overflow

Tags: script, stackoverflow

### About

Inspired by the reaction to [Beta release of Collectives™ on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408585/beta-release-of-collectives-on-stack-overflow?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C33.8669), I decided to create a small practical solution in the form of a user script.

It will remove almost all traces of Collectives™ on Stack Overflow:

- Tag-icons on posts.
- Award icons & small orange affiliation banner on user cards on posts.
- Box under the user avatar on user profiles.
- List item saying "X user groups" on user profiles.
- Box in the home page right sidebar.
- Answer endorsements ("Answer recommended by ...").

The exception is to the Collectives™ link in the left sidebar and the Collectives™ themselves. I wanted to keep this so that one can still go there and read about them.

#### Platform

Should work with any user script manager & any browser running JavaScript.
Tested (mostly by [10 Rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12708583)) on Windows 10 using

- Opera, Chrome & Edge with TamperMonkey.
- Firefox with ViolentMonkey.

### Contact

For bugs, please post here. Comments are fine too.

### Code

JavaScript using jQuery:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Stack Collectives Off
// @namespace    scratte-fiddlings
// @version      0.8
// @description  Pretending Collectives don't exist
// @author       Scratte (stackoverflow.com/users/12695027)
// @include      https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @exclude      https://stackoverflow.com/collectives*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

// NOTE: The script does not remove the "Explore Collectives" on the left sidebar.
//       It's still possible to go to a collectives site and check them out.

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Start with user profiles (since Stack removed the defining class on the links).
    document.querySelector("a[href*='\/collectives\/']")
           // Another optimization suggested by Oleg Valter
           // https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/52657512#52657512
           ?.closest("div.grid--item")
           ?.remove();

    // Suggested by Oleg Valter (https://stackoverflow.com/users/11407695)
    // https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/52657173#52657173
    const mostCollectivesStuff =
              [
                  // the collective on the home page right sidebar
                  ".js-join-leave-container",
                  // both 1: the collective icons from posts on the home page
                  //      2: the award icons from user cards on posts
                  "a[href*='\/collectives\/']:not(#nav-collective-discover)",
                  // the particular collective in the sidebar on posts
                  ".sidebar-subcommunity",
              ];

    const postCollectivesStuff =
              [
                  // orange affiliation banner from user profiles on posts
                  ".affiliate-badge",
                  // "Answer recommended by ..."
                  ".js-endorsements",
                  // recognized member icon in comments.
                  "div.comment-body span[title='Recognized Member']"
              ];

    document.querySelectorAll(mostCollectivesStuff.concat(postCollectivesStuff).join()) // "," is default
            .forEach(e => e.remove());

    const removePostCollectives = () => document.querySelectorAll(postCollectivesStuff.join()) // "," is default
            .forEach(e => e.remove());

    // And the list item saying "X user groups" from user profiles
    document.querySelector("ul div[aria-describedby=groups-popover]")
           ?.closest("li.flex--item")
           ?.remove();

    $(document) // needed for it to work with updates as in reviews
        .ajaxComplete((event, request, settings) => {
            removePostCollectives();
         });

})();
```

#### Download

[GitHub](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/tree/main/StackCollectivesOff) | [Install](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/raw/main/StackCollectivesOff/StackCollectivesOff.user.js)

Comment: You should make this into a gist, tag it with `.user.js`, so people can simply click/install, as opposed to creating a new script, pasting in code, etc.

Comment: @ughStackExchange Done. I usually don't do that with less than 100 lines of code. But since you asked :)

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When I turn on your script, I see that it hide the first element of Hot Meta Posts in Sidebar, as below:

[image: Preview]

When I turn you script off, everything is fine:

[image: Preview]

I face this bug in 0.1 & 0.2 and I am using Firefox 90.0.2.